# Additive property of KL-divergence

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, kullback-leibler

I am new to information theory and I want to know is there any conclusion about the relationship between $KL \left( p*a + (1-p)*b | c \right)$ and $p*KL \left( a | c \right) + (1-p) * KL \left( b | c \right)$? I know it does not trivially hold of $KL \left( p*a + (1-p)*b | c \right) \le p * KL \left( a | c \right) + (1-p) * KL \left( b | c \right)$, is there any condition can make it holds? Or other similar conclusion can make $\le$ holds. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If $a$ and $b$ are probability distributions, $a+b$ won't be since its integral will be equal to $2$. But, we can substitute and calculate the KL distance metric w/o minding the normalisation constant (with some abuse of notation):

$$\begin{align}KL(a+b|c)&=\int(a+b)\log \frac{a+b}{c}\\&=\int a\log \frac{a+b}{c} + \int b\log \frac{a+b}{c}\\&\geq\int a\log\frac{a}{c}+\int b\log\frac{b}{c}\\&=KL(a|c)+KL(b|c)\end{align}$$

The inequality holds because $a,b,c$ are non-negative functions and the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function.